# how to apply readonly property on select field in zf2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

readonly property not applied on selectbox.
here is my code of form:

```
array(
         'type' => 'Select',
         'name' => 'role',
         'attributes' => array(
             'id' => 'role',
            'error_msg' => 'Select User Role',
         ),
         'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Role'
         ),
        'validation' => array(
            'required'=>false,
            'filters'=> array(
                array('name'=>'StripTags'),
                array('name'=>'StringTrim')
            ),
            'validators'=>array(
                array(
                    'name'=>'StringLength',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
                        'min'=>1,
                        'max'=>250
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
```

controller code:

```
  $form->get('role')->setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
```

and in my controller i apply readonly property on selectbox but readonly property not applied how i apply readonly property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select don't have the readonly property. Here is the select description on [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html)

What you can do is disable the select and add a hidden field (if you wish to pass a default value)

Example:

```
$form->get('field_name')->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

or using the factory method:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'field_name',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Type',
        'value_options' => array(
            'val1'  => 'name1',
            'valN'      => 'nameN'
        ),
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'disabled' => 'disabled',
    ),
));
```

Comment: in this case you should use a hidden field to preserve existing data of "field_name"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my solution was:

1. I put the form element select to disabled.
2. I added the Form element into a formHidden and FormSelect.

Example in view phtml file:

```
$element = $form->get('name');
if ($isReadOnly) {
   echo $this->formHidden($element);
   $element->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
   echo $this->formSelect($element);  //Display the select to user
}
```

Hope it helps.